# Flutter TextOverflow not working, and causing RenderOverflow

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a chat app UI, and thought of using TextOverflow to fix the problem where the last sent message exceedes the size of the screen and causes Render Overflow. So I simply modified my Text widget, adding these 3 lines-

```
Text(
    widget.lastMessage,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    maxLines: 1,
    softWrap: true,
    style: const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
    ),
)
```

However, this made no difference-

[image]

Here's the code-

Main ListView-

```
import 'package:project_name/widgets/chat_preview_tile_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPreviewTileCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPreviewTileCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatPreviewTileCardState createState() => _ChatPreviewTileCardState();
}

class _ChatPreviewTileCardState extends State<ChatPreviewTileCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, n) {
          //Individual List Tile
          return const ChatPreviewTileWidget(
            username: "Person",
            imageUrl:
                "https://www.nme.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RickAstley2021.jpg",
            time: "9:30PM",
            hasUnreadMessage: true,
            lastMessage:
                "i am susssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssSSSSSSSSSSs",
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Individual Tile Widget-

```
import 'package:airing/screens/chat_screen/user_chat/user_chat_screen.dart';
import 'package:airing/utils/color_themes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatPreviewTileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String time;
  final bool hasUnreadMessage;
  final String lastMessage;
  const ChatPreviewTileWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.username,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.time,
    required this.hasUnreadMessage,
    required this.lastMessage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState createState() => _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState();
}

class _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState extends State<ChatPreviewTileWidget> {
  static int widgetsInScreen = 12;
  static int pfpPadding = 10;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return UserChatScreen(
                    imageUrl: widget.imageUrl, username: widget.username);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / widgetsInScreen,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 2.5),
              //main row
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  //Pfp, username and last message row
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          widget.imageUrl,
                        ),
                        radius: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                    widgetsInScreen) -
                                (2 * pfpPadding)) /
                            2,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.username,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: secondaryMainThemeColor),
                            ),
                            Text( //Here is the text message widget.
                              widget.lastMessage,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,    
                              maxLines: 1,
                              softWrap: true,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                  //sent and notification Column
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.time,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: secondaryMainThemeColor,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.circle_rounded,
                        color: mainThemeColor,
                        size: 15,
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Divider()
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Text `Column` with `Expanded` widget like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        widget.username,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: secondaryMainThemeColor),
      ),
      Text(
        //Here is the text message widget.
        widget.lastMessage,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 1,
        softWrap: true,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Hope It Works!

Answer (score 1):

```
Change your code to this:

    import 'package:airing/screens/chat_screen/user_chat/user_chat_screen.dart';
    import 'package:airing/utils/color_themes.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ChatPreviewTileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String username;
      final String imageUrl;
      final String time;
      final bool hasUnreadMessage;
      final String lastMessage;
      const ChatPreviewTileWidget({
        Key? key,
        required this.username,
        required this.imageUrl,
        required this.time,
        required this.hasUnreadMessage,
        required this.lastMessage,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState createState() => _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _ChatPreviewTileWidgetState extends State<ChatPreviewTileWidget> {
      static int widgetsInScreen = 12;
      static int pfpPadding = 10;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return UserChatScreen(
                        imageUrl: widget.imageUrl, username: widget.username);
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / widgetsInScreen,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 2.5),
                  //main row
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //Pfp, username and last message row
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              widget.imageUrl,
                            ),
                            radius: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                        widgetsInScreen) -
                                    (2 * pfpPadding)) /
                                2,
                          ),
**//here is the changes**
                     Expanded(child:     Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  widget.username,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: secondaryMainThemeColor),
                                ),
                                Text( //Here is the text message widget.
                                  widget.lastMessage,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,    
                                  maxLines: 1,
                                  softWrap: true,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
    
                      //sent and notification Column
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.time,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: secondaryMainThemeColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.circle_rounded,
                            color: mainThemeColor,
                            size: 15,
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider()
              ],
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Wrapping my text widget with a SizedBox with a defined width fixed it-

```
SizedBox(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.lastMessage,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                softWrap: true,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```